# Does feature detector(filter) has to be a sqaure matrix?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, filter

I am going through a course on Convolutional neural networks, where in the convolution step, the feature detector matrix was square shaped.
[image]

Is there any mathematical significance that Feature detector has to be square shaped?Can it be a rectangular matrix and yield better results? I know it might be completely irrelevant but I am a beginner ...Please excuse :)